# Content of asp.net does not visible in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an url in famenroll1.aspx page.  The code of the page is as follows :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="famenroll1.aspx.cs" Inherits="famenroll1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
<style>
#Enroll1_url{   
    padding: 1px !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;        
    background-color: #0B70BE;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center center , rgb(11, 112, 190) 0%, rgb(11, 112, 190) 100%) !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    border: 2px solid rgb(43, 125, 185) !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 28px !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.layers) {
            //Capture the MouseDown event.
            document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);

            //Disable the OnMouseDown event handler.
            document.onmousedown = function () {
                return false;
            };
        }
        else {
            //Disable the OnMouseUp event handler.
            document.onmouseup = function (e) {
                if (e != null && e.type == "mouseup") {
                    //Check the Mouse Button which is clicked.
                    if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
                        //If the Button is middle or right then disable.
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        //Disable the Context Menu event.
        document.oncontextmenu = function () {
            return false;
        };
    </script>
    <Script Language="VBScript" Src="GetLearn.vbs">
</head>
<body>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Enroll1_url" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Please Try Again" runat="server" />

    <p style="position:absolute !important; top:5px !important; left:4px !important;">

</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding famenroll1.aspx.cs page is as follows :

```
public partial class famenroll1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string name, app_user, ai_logid, finger, cust_type;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = Request.QueryString["name"];
         app_user = Request.QueryString["app_user"];
         ai_logid = Request.QueryString["ai_logid"];
         finger = Request.QueryString["finger"];
         cust_type = Request.QueryString["cust_type"];

        changeUrl();
    }

    void changeUrl()
    {
        Enroll1_url.NavigateUrl = "famenroll1.asp?name="+name+"&app_user="+app_user+"&ai_logid="+ai_logid+"&check=&finger=1&cust_type="+cust_type;
    }

}
```

But the content of the asp.net page are not showing . There is no hyperlink in the famenroll1.aspx when I run it . What can be the reason  ? Please help me .

Comment: What does it look like when you view the source of the page in your browser? You say the link is not displaying - it would be helpful to know if it is actually not present, or just not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a .vbs file from .aspx file.I think thats not the exact way of calling a .vbs script from a .aspx file.